# Pullback of an invertible sheaf through an isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, sheaf-cohomology

Consider an **isomorphism** of schemes $(f,f^{\#})(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\to(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$. Moreover let $\mathcal F$ be an invetible sheaf on $Y$ and  let $f^{*}\mathcal{F}$ be its pullback.

Is it true that $\chi(\mathcal{F})=\chi(f^{*}\mathcal{F})$? Clearly $\chi(\cdot)$ is the Euler-Poincaré characteristic of the sheaf.

Comment: Not a precise mathematical answer, but: Can you imagine a world in which this fails to be true?

Comment: No! of course, but I need to be sure :)

Comment: As @Nefertiti suggests I would say that the answer is yes without checking by hands.

Comment: One easily shows that the cohomology groups are the same, in particular the euler characteristics are the same.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, my previous question was not suggesting there is some doubt in the matter. Of course the answer is yes. What I was trying to convey was that, even without writing down a proof, the answer _must_ be yes, otherwise the notion of isomorphism is completely broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because $f^\ast$ is an exact functor if $f$ is an isomorphism.